# How do I copy a row of cells to reference on another workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 workbooks I am testing on. One is called 'BKC Daily Sales' , the other is 'Weekly Sales P&L'.
When I attempt to reference a string of cells from 'Daily Sales' (251D,251F,251H,251J,231L,251N,251P) and what those seven individual cells referenced on workbook 'Weekly Sales P&L' on cells 10B,10C,10D,10E,10F,10G,10H, obviously it sums them up on the first cell, 10B when I copy / paste the string.
[image: Image shows both files and highlighted areas I am referring to] 
I want to know if there is a way to copy a set of cells then paste a set from one workbook to another as a group. Currently I have to do them one by one and when creating a myriad of workbooks for P&N analysis; budgets, daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly sales, this will take forever to reference cells one by one from various workbook.

Comment: As a general advice, I would not mix data and presentation as you have in your example. Nearly all of my data goes into a single sheet called "Data" which does all of the calculations I need. Then, I use a sheet with nicely formatted outputs (like yours) with formulas that pull data from that "Data" sheet. It makes everything about a million times easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paste Special to paste links as opposed to values or formulas. This will be under the Home menu on the ribbon. I'm not on a Mac, so this is what it looks like on Windows:

[image]